# Dice game that requires us to number our turns along with adding * before every dice roll

Tags: c++, function, dice

visit http://voyager.deanza.edu/~bentley/ass5.html

My goal is trying to match the sample output that is on the link. The only obstacles that I can not seem to overcome is how to add what turn you are on and also "*" before each line dice roll.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int roll();
int turn();


int main ()
{
srand(time(0));

int gameTotal = 0;

while (gameTotal < 100)
{

    gameTotal += turn();
    cout << "Your total is now " << gameTotal << endl << endl;;
 }


 }

int turn()
{
int turnTotal = 0;
int temp;


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    temp = roll();
    if (temp == 7) break;
    turnTotal += temp;

}
cout << "You scored " << turnTotal << " points for this turn" << endl;
return turnTotal;
}

int roll()
{
int die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
int die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

int sum = die1 + die2;



 cout << "You rolled a " << die1 << " and " << die2 << ".  " << "That's " << sum << endl;
return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please share whatever code you have and describe in detail how you're "stuck". Also we don't do your homework.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Still new to this site. Just attached my code. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: This is a bit tricky because you've mixed the output into the computations.

Comment: Care to elaborate a little bit more? *Still very new to C++.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable to store the number of turns played and update it at every turn. adding the `*` is even simplier:

```
int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));

    int gameTotal = 0;
    int turns = 0;

    while (gameTotal < 100)
    {
        // update number of turns and output it
        ++turns;
        cout << "This is your turn #" << turns << endl;

        gameTotal += turn();
        cout << "*** Your total is now " << gameTotal << endl << endl;
        //       ^^^ easy
    }
}
```

Similar changes in the other functions:

```
cout << "** You scored " << turnTotal << " points for this turn" << endl;
//       ^^
```

and

```
cout << "* You rolled a " << die1 << " and " << die2 << ".  " << "That's " << sum << endl;
//       ^
```

Comment: You my friend, are the REAL MVP... Thanks man. Really helpful.

Comment: @JoseVasquez You are welcome. If it helped, you may also consider to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer.